# Create webrtc video, voice call and file transfer using node js step by step Q-A

Tags: node.js, express, https, socket.io, webrtc

> If any one  need to add information or edit some information they are welcome.

Hi,
First of  all   this  questions main target is  shear my  experience to  other developers who finding good tutorials about webrtc.i'm  not  going  to explain about webrtc. In  this i add  scourse  code that working  webrtc Video, voice call and  file  transfer example tested by me.

> I get webrtc  information  from  https://webrtc.org/ and  get nodejs
>   from https://nodejs.org/en/

Ok let  get start

> **Is  web rtc  need  ssl certificated?**

If  you  doing  experiment in you local PC server  no need.  but when  you add  the to live server  Yes  you  need  it.

> **How  i get  ssl certificate?**

one  of  my friend   help  me to  get  that SSl. there  plenty of   tutorials for you read and  watch

> **How  i get  turn and stun server?**

if you go production level  you need to setup those server , but  for test your  project you can get  stun server and  turn servers  for  free.

For Stun server  -  https://gist.github.com/zziuni/3741933

For  Turn server   - Use this link and create free one ( http://numb.viagenie.ca/ ).

I add my working code as a an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This  is  Working  code  for  webrtc with node js

> This  code and  comment that in code not by me. They already there when i got the code. I cant  find code original owner.  but i thanks that developer.If  some found  that developer please  edit this  and add that developer link :)

```js
var express = require('express');

var socket = require('socket.io');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');

// link  your  https  certicate  path 
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/../../etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/../../etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt')
};


var main = https.createServer(options, app);

var server = main.listen(8443, function() {
    console.log('server up and running at %s port', 8443);
});

/*var server = app.listen(443, function () {
});*/
app.use(express.static('public'));
var io = socket(server);
/*************************/
/*** INTERESTING STUFF ***/
/*************************/
var channels = {};
var sockets = {};
/**
 * Users will connect to the signaling server, after which they'll issue a "join"
 * to join a particular channel. The signaling server keeps track of all sockets
 * who are in a channel, and on join will send out 'addPeer' events to each pair
 * of users in a channel. When clients receive the 'addPeer' even they'll begin
 * setting up an RTCPeerConnection with one another. During this process they'll
 * need to relay ICECandidate information to one another, as well as SessionDescription
 * information. After all of that happens, they'll finally be able to complete
 * the peer connection and will be streaming audio/video between eachother.
 */
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var channel;
    socket.channels = {};
    sockets[socket.id] = socket;
    console.log("[" + socket.id + "] connection accepted");
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        for (var channel in socket.channels) {
            part(channel);
        }
        console.log("[" + socket.id + "] disconnected");
        delete sockets[socket.id];
    });
    socket.on('join-room', function (config) {
        if (config) {
            channel = config.channel;
            var userdata = config.userdata;
            var userID = config.userdata.userID;
            if (channel in socket.channels) {
                console.log("[" + socket.id + "] ERROR: already joined ", channel);
                return;
            }
            if (!(channel in channels)) {
                channels[channel] = {};
            }
            for (id in channels[channel]) {
                channels[channel][id].emit('addPeer-room', {'peer_id': socket.id, 'should_create_offer': false});
                socket.emit('addPeer-room', {'peer_id': id, 'should_create_offer': true});
                console.log("what  is this  id -> ", id);
            }
            console.log(config.userdata.name, ' joining room', config.channel);
            socket.join(config.channel);
            socket.broadcast.in(config.channel).emit('room-users', config);
            channels[channel][socket.id] = socket;
            socket.channels[channel] = channel;
        }
    });
    function part(channel) {
        console.log("[" + socket.id + "] part ");
        if (!(channel in socket.channels)) {
            console.log("[" + socket.id + "] ERROR: not in ", channel);
            return;
        }
        delete socket.channels[channel];
        delete channels[channel][socket.id];
        for (id in channels[channel]) {
            channels[channel][id].emit('removePeer', {'peer_id': socket.id});
            socket.emit('removePeer', {'peer_id': id});
        }
    }

    socket.on('part', part);
    socket.on('relayICECandidate-room', function (config) {
        var peer_id = config.peer_id;
        var ice_candidate = config.ice_candidate;
        console.log("[" + socket.id + "] relaying ICE candidate to [" + peer_id + "] ", ice_candidate);
        if (peer_id in sockets) {
            sockets[peer_id].emit('iceCandidate-room', {'peer_id': socket.id, 'ice_candidate': ice_candidate});
        }
    });
    socket.on('relaySessionDescription-room', function (config) {
        var peer_id = config.peer_id;
        var session_description = config.session_description;
        console.log("[" + socket.id + "] relaying session description to [" + peer_id + "] ", session_description);
        if (peer_id in sockets) {
            sockets[peer_id].emit('sessionDescription-room', {
                'peer_id': socket.id,
                'session_description': session_description
            });
        }
    });
    // this for  file  transfer
    socket.on('file-send-room', function (file) {
        console.log(file);
        socket.to(channel).emit('file-out-room', file);
    });
    socket.on('file-send-room-result', function (file) {
        console.log(file);
        socket.to(channel).emit('file-out-room-result', file);
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <script>
        function getParameterByName(name, url) {
            if (!url) url = window.location.href;
            name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
            var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
                results = regex.exec(url);
            if (!results) return null;
            if (!results[2]) return '';
            return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }
        var fileInput = document.querySelector('input#fileInput');
        var downloadAnchor = document.querySelector('a#download');
        
        // this function use to get url parameters
        
        
        var room = getParameterByName('room');
        var userID = getParameterByName('userid');
        var name = getParameterByName('name');
        /** CONFIG **/
        var SIGNALING_SERVER = "https://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:8443"; //your  node server addres  or  IP adress
        var USE_AUDIO = true;
        var USE_VIDEO = true;
        var MUTE_AUDIO_BY_DEFAULT = false;
        /** You should probably use a different stun server doing commercial stuff **/
        /** Also see: https://gist.github.com/zziuni/3741933 **/
        var ICE_SERVERS = [
            {urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"},{
                urls: 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca:3478',
                credential: '12344', //your  password
                username: 'your@email.com'
            }
        ];
        var socket = null;
        /* our socket.io connection to our webserver */
        var local_media_stream = null;
        /* our own microphone / webcam */
        var peers = {};
        /* keep track of our peer connections, indexed by peer_id (aka socket.io id) */
        var peer_media_elements = {};
        /* keep track of our <video>/<audio> tags, indexed by peer_id */
        $(document).ready(function (a) {
            socket = io(SIGNALING_SERVER);
            socket = io();
            //----------------------------------------------------------------------->>>>> Files Send Start
            const BYTES_PER_CHUNK = 1200;
            var file;
            var currentChunk;
            var fileInput = $('input[type=file]');
            var fileReader = new FileReader();

            function readNextChunk() {
                var start = BYTES_PER_CHUNK * currentChunk;
                var end = Math.min(file.size, start + BYTES_PER_CHUNK);
                fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file.slice(start, end));
            }

            fileReader.onload = function () {
                socket.emit('file-send-room-result', fileReader.result);
                //p2pConnection.send( fileReader.result );
                currentChunk++;
                if (BYTES_PER_CHUNK * currentChunk < file.size) {
                    readNextChunk();
                }
            };
            fileInput.on('change', function () {
                file = fileInput[0].files[0];
                currentChunk = 0;
                // send some metadata about our file
                // to the receiver
                socket.emit('file-send-room', JSON.stringify({
                    fileName: file.name,
                    fileSize: file.size
                }));
                readNextChunk();
            });
            var incomingFileInfo;
            var incomingFileData;
            var bytesReceived;
            var downloadInProgress = false;
            socket.on('file-out-room', function (data) {
                startDownload(data);

                console.log(data);
            });
            socket.on('file-out-room-result', function (data) {
                progressDownload(data);
                console.log(data);            });
            function startDownload(data) {
                incomingFileInfo = JSON.parse(data.toString());
                incomingFileData = [];
                bytesReceived = 0;
                downloadInProgress = true;
                console.log('incoming file <b>' + incomingFileInfo.fileName + '</b> of ' + incomingFileInfo.fileSize + ' bytes');
            }

            function progressDownload(data) {
                bytesReceived += data.byteLength;
                incomingFileData.push(data);
                console.log('progress: ' + ((bytesReceived / incomingFileInfo.fileSize ) * 100).toFixed(2) + '%');
                if (bytesReceived === incomingFileInfo.fileSize) {
                    endDownload();
                }
            }

            function endDownload() {
                downloadInProgress = false;
                var blob = new Blob(incomingFileData);
               
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.style = "display: none";
                var blob = new Blob(incomingFileData);
                var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                a.href = url;
                a.download = incomingFileInfo.fileName;
                a.click();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            }

            //==================================================================<<< Filse Send End
            //------------------------ Funtion
            function join_chat_channel(channel, userdata) {
                socket.emit('join-room', {"channel": channel, "userdata": userdata});
            }

            socket.on('connect', function (userID) {
                console.log("Connected to signaling server");
                setup_local_media(function () {
                    /* once the user has given us access to their
                     * microphone/camcorder, join the channel and start peering up */
                    join_chat_channel(room, {'name': name, 'userID': userID});
                });
            });
            socket.on('room-user', function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $("#online-user").append('<tr><td>Name = ' + data.userdata.name + ' <br> User ID= ' + data.userdata.userID + '</td><td><button class="call" id="' + data.userdata.userID + '">Call</button></td></tr>');
            });
            $('body').on('click', '.call', function () {
                var callerID = $(this).attr('id');
            
                socket.emit('call', {"callToId": callerID, "callFromId": userID});
            });
            /**
             * When we join a group, our signaling server will send out 'addPeer' events to each pair
             * of users in the group (creating a fully-connected graph of users, ie if there are 6 people
             * in the channel you will connect directly to the other 5, so there will be a total of 15
             * connections in the network).
             */
            socket.on('addPeer-room', function (config) {
                console.log('Signaling server said to add peer:', config);
                var peer_id = config.peer_id;
                if (peer_id in peers) {
                    /* This could happen if the user joins multiple channels where the other peer is also in. */
                    console.log("Already connected to peer ", peer_id);
                    return;
                }
                var peer_connection = new RTCPeerConnection(
                    {"iceServers": ICE_SERVERS},
                    {"optional": [{"DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement": true}]} /* this will no longer be needed by chrome
                         * eventually (supposedly), but is necessary
                         * for now to get firefox to talk to chrome */
                );
                peers[peer_id] = peer_connection;
                peer_connection.onicecandidate = function (event) {
                    if (event.candidate) {
                        socket.emit('relayICECandidate-room', {
                            'peer_id': peer_id,
                            'ice_candidate': {
                                'sdpMLineIndex': event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
                                'candidate': event.candidate.candidate
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                peer_connection.onaddstream = function (event) {
                    console.log("onAddStream", event);
                    var remote_media = USE_VIDEO ? $("<video>") : $("<audio>");
                    remote_media.attr("autoplay", "autoplay");
                    if (MUTE_AUDIO_BY_DEFAULT) {
                        remote_media.attr("muted", "true");
                    }
                    remote_media.attr("controls", "");
                    peer_media_elements[peer_id] = remote_media;
                    $('body').append(remote_media);
                    attachMediaStream(remote_media[0], event.stream);
                }
                /* Add our local stream */
                peer_connection.addStream(local_media_stream);
                /* Only one side of the peer connection should create the
                 * offer, the signaling server picks one to be the offerer.
                 * The other user will get a 'sessionDescription' event and will
                 * create an offer, then send back an answer 'sessionDescription' to us
                 */
                if (config.should_create_offer) {
                    console.log("Creating RTC offer to ", peer_id);
                    peer_connection.createOffer(
                        function (local_description) {
                            console.log("Local offer description is: ", local_description);
                            peer_connection.setLocalDescription(local_description,
                                function () {
                                    socket.emit('relaySessionDescription-room',
                                        {'peer_id': peer_id, 'session_description': local_description});
                                    console.log("Offer setLocalDescription succeeded");
                                },
                                function () {
                                    Alert("Offer setLocalDescription failed!");
                                }
                            );
                        },
                        function (error) {
                            console.log("Error sending offer: ", error);
                        });
                }
            });
            /**
             * Peers exchange session descriptions which contains information
             * about their audio / video settings and that sort of stuff. First
             * the 'offerer' sends a description to the 'answerer' (with type
             * "offer"), then the answerer sends one back (with type "answer").
             */
            socket.on('sessionDescription-room', function (config) {
                console.log('Remote description received: ', config);
                var peer_id = config.peer_id;
                var peer = peers[peer_id];
                var remote_description = config.session_description;
                console.log(config.session_description);
                var desc = new RTCSessionDescription(remote_description);
                var stuff = peer.setRemoteDescription(desc,
                    function () {
                        console.log("setRemoteDescription succeeded");
                        if (remote_description.type == "offer") {
                            console.log("Creating answer");
                            peer.createAnswer(
                                function (local_description) {
                                    console.log("Answer description is: ", local_description);
                                    peer.setLocalDescription(local_description,
                                        function () {
                                            socket.emit('relaySessionDescription-room',
                                                {'peer_id': peer_id, 'session_description': local_description});
                                            console.log("Answer setLocalDescription succeeded");
                                        },
                                        function () {
                                            Alert("Answer setLocalDescription failed!");
                                        }
                                    );
                                },
                                function (error) {
                                    console.log("Error creating answer: ", error);
                                    console.log(peer);
                                });
                        }
                    },
                    function (error) {
                        console.log("setRemoteDescription error: ", error);
                    }
                );
                console.log("Description Object: ", desc);
            });
            /**
             * The offerer will send a number of ICE Candidate blobs to the answerer so they
             * can begin trying to find the best path to one another on the net.
             */
            socket.on('iceCandidate-room', function (config) {
                var peer = peers[config.peer_id];
                var ice_candidate = config.ice_candidate;
                peer.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(ice_candidate));
            });
            /**
             * When a user leaves a channel (or is disconnected from the
             * signaling server) everyone will recieve a 'removePeer' message
             * telling them to trash the media channels they have open for those
             * that peer. If it was this client that left a channel, they'll also
             * receive the removePeers. If this client was disconnected, they
             * wont receive removePeers, but rather the
             * signaling_socket.on('disconnect') code will kick in and tear down
             * all the peer sessions.
             */
            socket.on('removePeer-room', function (config) {
                console.log('Signaling server said to remove peer:', config);
                var peer_id = config.peer_id;
                if (peer_id in peer_media_elements) {
                    peer_media_elements[peer_id].remove();
                }
                if (peer_id in peers) {
                    peers[peer_id].close();
                }
                delete peers[peer_id];
                delete peer_media_elements[config.peer_id];
            });
        });
        function setup_local_media(callback, errorback) {
            if (local_media_stream != null) {  /* ie, if we've already been initialized */
                if (callback) callback();
                return;
            }
            /* Ask user for permission to use the computers microphone and/or camera,
             * attach it to an <audio> or <video> tag if they give us access. */
            console.log("Requesting access to local audio / video inputs");
            navigator.getUserMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.msGetUserMedia);
            attachMediaStream = function (element, stream) {
                console.log('DEPRECATED, attachMediaStream will soon be removed.');
                element.srcObject = stream;
            };
            navigator.getUserMedia({"audio": USE_AUDIO, "video": USE_VIDEO},
                function (stream) { /* user accepted access to a/v */
                    console.log("Access granted to audio/video");
                    local_media_stream = stream;
                    var local_media = USE_VIDEO ? $("<video>") : $("<audio>");
                    local_media.attr("autoplay", "autoplay");
                    local_media.attr("muted", "true");
                    /* always mute ourselves by default */
                    local_media.attr("controls", "");
                    $('body').append(local_media);
                    attachMediaStream(local_media[0], stream);
                    if (callback) callback();
                },
                function () { /* user denied access to a/v */
                    console.log("Access denied for audio/video");
                    alert("You chose not to provide access to the camera/microphone, demo will not work.");
                    if (errorback) errorback();
                });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="fileInfo">
    <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="files"/>
</form>
<a id="download"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, can you guide me bit more about this? I have to implement it in my Linux operating system. Need guide about the server configuration and where to place the code files?